# Create mongoose plugin with typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, plugins

I have found on the internet this interesting [article](http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/03/06/guide-to-mongoose-plugins) about plugins in mongoose. From that site I got this code:

```
    function HidePlugin(schema) {
  var toHide = [];
  schema.eachPath(function(pathname, schemaType) {
    if (schemaType.options && schemaType.options.hide) {
      toHide.push(pathname);
    }    
  });
  schema.options.toObject = schema.options.toObject || {};
  schema.options.toObject.transform = function(doc, ret) {
    // Loop over all fields to hide
    toHide.forEach(function(pathname) {
      // Break the path up by dots to find the actual
      // object to delete
      var sp = pathname.split('.');
      var obj = ret;
      for (var i = 0; i < sp.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (!obj) {
          return;
        }
        obj = obj[sp[i]];
      }
      // Delete the actual field
      delete obj[sp[sp.length - 1]];
    });

    return ret;
  };
}
```

The problem is that I use typescript together with node.js. The typescript compiler gives me errors because there are no explicit types. In fact, I do not know exactly what type I have to attribute to the variables in the code